# How to put a menu Icon in odoo 9?

Tags: menuitem, odoo-9

I want to put a menu icon for the hr_attendance addon in odoo 9.

I will explain the steps that i have done:

1. Create hr_attendance_extend an put it in addon_extra
2. Import the original addon. This is "**init**.py":

   ```
   import hr_attendance
   ```
3. Create the css and put the icon. This is a piece of the file "static/src/css/slider.css":

   ```
   ...     
   .oe_systray .oe_attendance_signout {        
       float:right;        
       height: 32px;       
       width: 32px;        
       background: url(/hr_attendance_extend/static/src/img/emp-in32.png);     
       cursor: pointer;        
   }       
   ...
   ```
4. Link the file with the addon. This is the file ''views/hr_attendance.xml":

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <openerp>
           <data>
               <template id="assets_backend" name="hr_attendance assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
                   <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/hr_attendance_extend/static/src/css/slider.css"/>
                   </xpath>
               </template>
           </data>
       </openerp>
   ```
5. Put the new files in the new addon. This is part of the file "**openerp**.py":

   ```
   {
   ...
   'depends': ['hr_attendance'],
       'data': [
           'hr_attendance.xml',
           'views/hr_attendance.xml',
       ],
       'demo': [],
       'test': [],
       'installable': True,
       'auto_install': False,
       #web 
       'qweb' : ["static/src/xml/attendance.xml"],
   }
   ```
6. Put the container for the menu. This is the file ''static/src/xml/attendance.xml":

   ```
   <template>
       <t t-name="AttendanceSlider">
       <li class="oe_attendance_status oe_attendance_nosigned" data-toggle="tooltip">
                 <div class="oe_attendance_signout"></div>
           </li>
       </t>
   </template>
   ```

In the original addon (hr_attendance) there is a function that it pushes the icon to the menu (I think).

There is in the file static/src/js/attendance.js and that is the line in question:

```
SystrayMenu.Items.push(AttendanceSlider);
```

That's all.

I don't know if I am missing something.  The code of the icon appears in the html, but there is with 'style="display: none"'

**Edit**:
If I change the css file putting the property "display: block !important", then, the icon appears in the menu, but that fix is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for another problem which shares the same solution as here.

These are the steps for a new user:

1. Log in as administrator
2. Employees > Employees > Create button (Fill the name)
3. Select the "HR Settings" tab > Related User -> Create and edit (Fill the name and email).
4. Save the user and save the employee.
5. Go to Developer mode (User menu > About > Activate the developer mode)
6. Settings > User > Select the new created user > Edit > Mark the option "Attendances"
7. Save the user.

Now, the icon appears.